# While resetting the form custom object with start and end changed to null

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Am using ngx-daterangepicker-material DaterangePicker component with the Angular 2 form. Within the form am trying to reset the component. on that case the custom object with start and end changed to null within the form json.

The Initial value type of the Component before form reset :

```
let range: any = {start:new Date('2/2/2017'), end:new Date('3/3/2017')}

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({

  customrange: [range, [Validators.minLength(3)]],

});

  "customrange": {

    "startDate": "2018-07-16T18:30:00.000Z",

    "endDate": "2018-08-21T18:29:59.000Z"

  }
```

After the form rest the custom object changed to null:

```
{ 
  "customrange": null,
}
```

Whether it is a behaviour or anything workaround to fix this.

Demo link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hjem9h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Reference link:
https://fetrarij.github.io/ngx-daterangepicker-material/full

Comment: How do you reset form? Can you provide minimal example?

Comment: Hi @Justinas,
//HTML 
 <input type="text" matInput ngxDaterangepickerMd  formControlName="customrange" name="customrange" />
  <div>
        <button type="reset" class=" btn btn-primary" (click)="ResetForm() ">
    Reset
    </div> 
  ngOnInit() {
    let range: any = {start:new Date('2/2/2017'), end:new Date('3/3/2017')}
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      customrange: [range, [Validators.minLength(3)]],
    });
  }
// Rest Handler
  ResetForm(args: any) {
    this.form.reset();
  }

Comment: Edit your question, and not put code to comment

Comment: @Justinas, Do you need any further details regarding this.

Comment: https://github.com/thirukumarangceb/Form/blob/master/src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1):

This is how `reset` function works. You need to pass the object which you want the `reset` function to set the new value to instead of `null`.

So just do:

```
this.form.get('customrange').reset(range);
```

Comment: yeah, this works. @Chrillewoodz,  but in my case am having multiple components. i will be resetting the form in common (this.form.reset() ). how to achieve this. At the same time it is a common behaviour (resetting to null ) we need to do the above workaround to maintain the custom object value within the form.

Comment: Check with the below sample link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-372cqs?file=src/app/app.component.ts